# Fill missing dates in records - Nodejs Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using this query to get count of orders for 7 days of currently week. The result I get is something like this:

```
[
   { _id: '2021-01-31', orders: 3 },
   { _id: '2021-02-01', orders: 1 },
   { _id: '2021-02-02', orders: 2 },
   { _id: '2021-02-06', orders: 2 }
]
```

The problem is that if there was no order on specific day, the orders count should be 0 for that date. For example `{ _id: '2021-02-03', orders: 0 }`, there was no order on 03-02-2021 it should be 0.

This is the query that I'm using:

```
    let d = new Date()
    d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay()||7));
    let yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    let weekNumber = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
const ordersweekly = await Order.aggregate([
        {
          "$set": { "date": { "$week": "$createdAt" } }
        },
        {
          "$match": { "date": weekNumber }
        },
        {
          "$set": { "date": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$createdAt" } } }
        },
        {
          "$group": { "_id": "$date", "orders": { "$sum": 1 } }
        },
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
    ])
```

Comment: You have to do it in client side in nodejs, just prepare weekly object with `orders:0` and after query merge result with that objects.